# Grabbing number from id tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<ul style="display: block;">

<li id="deviceTree_3" class="device">

<div class="tree-itemBody ">

<div class="triCheck"</div>

<div class="tree-arrowPlaceholder"></div>

<span class="tree-itemContent">Bath Vanity (na)</span>

</div>
</li>
```

The idea is to get the number after the deviceTree_#

The issue im running into is the number can be various lengths ie ....583 or 3

is this a regex situation or is there something a simpler solution

Comment: you can use `alert(("deviceTree_3000").split("_")[1])`

Comment: why not leave that as an answer

Comment: you html is invalid. Please add at least a few closing tags, or better yet remove everything but `<li id="deviceTree_3" class="device">` as this is the only part necessary

Comment: @tman I have place my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always "deviceTree_" followed by the number then you can use the below:

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName('device')[0].id;
var idNum = id.substring(id.indexOf('_')+1,id.length);
console.log(idNum);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var tempname=$("#deviceTree_3").attr("id").split("_");

alert(tempname[1]);//show 3
```

reference **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

Comment: Is there any reason the fiddle of this is not showing anything? I may be doing something wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/9NfFQ/

Comment: thanks for your answer! Why was the last line changed from tempname to numtemp?

Comment: because you alert variable so it is same in alert box

Answer (score 1):

If your number value is always behind the `_` you can get it by

```
var numberTag = $('#deviceTree_3').attr('id').split('_').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `$("#deviceTree_3").attr("id").split("_")[1]`.
Simple and sweet

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the part of the id after `_`. You don't need jQuery here. A function taking an element with an id of the form `[anything]_[number]` could be:

```
function numberFromId(domElem) {
  var idParts = domElem.id.split("_");
  return idParts[1] ? idParts[1] : null;
}
```

I included this code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh6dG/)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will extract numeric part from any id, no matter if it's on begin or on end or in the middle:

```
id = 'fda_335534'
var reg = /(?![0-9])*([0-9]+)/
var match = reg.exec(id)
console.log(match[1])
```

The plus is, it's working for any id structure.

If the id starts always with 'deviceTree_', and there's nothing after the num, just do:

```
console.log(id.replace('deviceTree_',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

If you want to get all `li` elements that has `deviceTree_NNNN` as `ID`, using `jQuery` you can do the following:

```
$.each( $("li[id^='deviceTree_']"), function () {
  var id_parts = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
  console.log( id_parts[1] );
});
```

For a single `li`:

```
var id_parts = $("li[id^='deviceTree_']").attr("id").split("_");
console.log(id_parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it.

`alert(("deviceTree_3000").split("_")[1])`;